# How do you get cucumber/guard to filter on tags like @wip?

Tags: cucumber, spork, guard

I'm running spork and guard and all has been going very well with my RSpec tests which were all run correctly. In order to speed up the tests I could successfully filter my RSpec tests with tags I placed in my `.rspec` file.

**.rspec**

```
--colour
--debug
--tag focus
--tag now
```

Unfortunately though I have not been able to filter my cucumber tags. Every time cucumber runs it runs either *everything* or just the file that changed.

How can I get cucumber/spork/guard to respect tags like @wip, @now etc and run only those tests? Is there some equivalent to the `.rspec` file for cucumber tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a cucumber profile to define the tags that you want to execute. Using the YML file, you can define a profile that execute your @wip tags:

```
wip: --tags @wip
```

More info at:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/cucumber.yml

You can also just run cucumber from the command line and pass it the -t argument:

```
cucumber -t @wip,@now
```

From the help (cucumber -h):

> Only execute the features or scenarios with tags matching
>   TAG_EXPRESSION.
>                                        Scenarios inherit tags declared on the Feature level. The simplest
>                                        TAG_EXPRESSION is simply a tag. Example: --tags @dev. When a tag in a tag
>                                        expression starts with a ~, this represents boolean NOT. Example: --tags ~@dev.
>                                        A tag expression can have several tags separated by a comma, which represents
>                                        logical OR. Example: --tags @dev,@wip. The --tags option can be specified
>                                        several times, and this represents logical AND. Example: --tags @foo,~@bar --tags @zap.
>                                        This represents the boolean expression (@foo || !@bar) && @zap

Hence, in theory we can use the guardfile with these options:

```
guard 'cucumber', :cli => "--drb --tags @now" do
  watch(%r{^features/.+\.feature$})
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that Dan. I can run tags from the command line but I can't as far as I know pass options to the `bundle exec guard` command so as you suggest the profile file has to be the key. I'll come back when I can confirm I've got it working

Comment: Hi Dan, I've just tried your suggestion and although I can't get it to work I suspect it's my error in implementation. I'd like to mark your answer as the correct one. Could you incorporate the answer I put below to show how to pass command line arguments via the guardfile. If you can do that then I'll delete mine and mark yours as right.

Comment: Hows that Pete? Let me know your comments.

Comment: thanks Dan - for some reason it didn't tell me you'd commented - now marked as correct though. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

An important concept to understand is there is a difference between **tags** and **profiles**.  I am also using Guard with Cucumber and was frustrated that the default profile continued to be used and none of my @wip (Work In Progress) tags were being picked up.  It's obvious now why that was the case.  As stated by some in other forums, my default profile filters out @wip.

<config/cucumber.yml>

```
<%
rerun = File.file?('rerun.txt') ? IO.read('rerun.txt') : ""
rerun_opts = rerun.to_s.strip.empty? ? "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'progress'} features" : "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} #{rerun}"
base_opts = "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'}"
std_opts = "#{base_opts} --strict --tags ~@wip"
wip_opts = base_opts
%>
default: --drb <%= std_opts %> features
wip: --drb <%= wip_opts %> --tags @wip:3 --wip features
rerun: --drb <%= rerun_opts %> --format rerun --out rerun.txt --strict --tags ~@wip
```

"std_opts = "#{base_opts} --strict **--tags ~@wip**"   <= *wip is filtered out here in std_opts*

I want to use the 'wip' profile, which would include scenarios or features marked by '@wip'!

wip: --drb <%= wip_opts %> **--tags @wip:3** --wip features"   <= *the number represents the max number of scenarios to run; '--wip' indicates that Cuc expects the test will fail (because we're working on it)*

So the tags are already configured and I've included '@wip' in my *.feature file.  What about the profiles?  When using Guard (Spork), in order for the 'wip' profile to be used, it needs to be configured.  It makes sense; the computer can't read my mind!  Update the Guardfile to use the 'wip' profile.

<Guardfile>

```
guard 'cucumber', :cli => "--drb -p wip", :all_on_start => false, :all_after_pass => false do
  watch(%r{^features/.+\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^features/support/.+$})          { 'features' }
  watch(%r{^features/step_definitions/(.+)_steps\.rb$}) { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'features' }
end
```

guard 'cucumber', :cli => "--drb **-p wip**"   <= *'-p' to specify desired profile*

And now my scenarios are successfully being filtered by 'wip'.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure when this option was introduced but guard-cucumber has the ability to focus on a particular tag (which is different than hard-coding a specific tag to always filter by). You can leave this configuration option in your Guardfile and only use your focus tag when you need it:

```
# Guardfile
guard 'cucumber', :focus_on => 'myfocustag' do
  ...
end

# example.feature
Feature: Example

  @myfocustag
  Scenario: Only run this one
  ...
```

cucumber-guard will then filter these scenarios before passing them to the cucumber command. Removing these tags would result in the default behavior (running all scenarios, rather than none).

Answer (score 0):

Although in theory it should be possible to make this work using cucumber profiles I found I had to use the `guardfile`.

**Original guardfile**

```
guard 'cucumber', :cli => "--drb" do
  watch(%r{^features/.+\.feature$})
  ...
end
```

**modified guardfile**

```
guard 'cucumber', :cli => "--drb --tags @now" do
  watch(%r{^features/.+\.feature$})
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Now if you want Guard to always run @wip like me then in your add:

**cucumber.yml**

```
guard: --format pretty --tags @wip
```

**Guardfile**

```ruby
guard 'cucumber', :command_prefix => 'spring', :cli => '--profile guard', :bundler => false do
  # your watches
end
```

that a watched file is modified then only @wip is going to be run but also when you type `cucumber` in the guard console.