# Cucumber: @wip flag behaves strangely with Guard

Tags: cucumber, scenarios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get cucumber/guard to filter on tags like @wip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193120/how-do-you-get-cucumber-guard-to-filter-on-tags-like-wip)

I have the following scenarios:

```
Feature: List projects
  In order to manage projects
  As a user
  I want to see a list of them

  Background:
    Given I am logged in

  @wip
  Scenario: I go to the projects
    When  I go to the projects
    Then  I should see a list of projects

  Scenario: I go to the projects2
    When  I go to the projects
    Then  I should see a list of projects
```

When running it (by saving it so it is invoked by Guard),  only the 2nd one is executed, as expected. But when saving any other feature (that also makes this feature run), the @wip tag seems to be ignored. Is this normal behavior?

**Update**

By using `--tags ~@ignore` I can disable as many features as I like. I'm still not really getting how @wip works (or better: why it works the way it works).

Comment: If you want to ask another (though very similar) question, specify it either below your question or (better) ask new question. Don't change your question because answers that you have already received become irrelevant after it.

Comment: I don't understand "But when saving any other feature (that also makes this feature run), the @wip tag seems to be ignored.". Could you explain?

Comment: I have guard running, which automatically runs all the features when the feature I currently work on passes.

Answer (score 1):

You can run all scenarios without this [tag](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags) using:

```
cucumber --tags ~@ignore
```

Comment: Note that after posting of question this answer was correct but later question was revised.